# Service not available inside ionicPlatform.ready

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

I need to use a service inside ionicplatform.ready event, however when used inside the callback function its not defined?

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, UserService) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    //UserService not available here

   });
 })
.factory('UserService', function() {
   return {};
 })
```

Any ideas how to get it to work?

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You should inject your dependencies like this `.run(['$ionicPlatform', 'UserService', function($ionicPlatform, UserService) {
   ...
}]); `

Comment: UserService is not defined is the error, I tried injecting as you suggested and still does not work.